# Can you pass multiple parameters via Durandal activationData compose binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

In the below code snippets (which do not error out), I want to pass in 2 parameters to the `activationData` because the `prototype.activate` function can take two parameters. Neither of them work.

```
<div data-bind="compose: {model: 'views/pageView', activationData: paperId, bookId}">
</div>

<div data-bind="compose: {model: 'views/pageView', activationData: (paperId, bookId)}">
</div>
```

The first param gets through, but the second is always undefined.   I have verified it has a value on the view making the compose call.

Can you pass multiple parameters via activationData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, you just need to encapsulate the parameters on a new object:

```
<div data-bind="compose: {model: 'views/pageView', activationData: {paperId: paperId, bookId: bookId}}">
</div>
```